# Cocoa: Setting Mac window full screen the view doesn't change size

Tags: cocoa, swift4, xcode9, nsview, nswindow

I'm setting up window to be able to be full screen:

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
        window?.collectionBehavior = [.fullScreenPrimary]
    }
}
```

And the window works fine but the view doesn't go full screen

[image]

any of you knows what I need to do to set the view full screen as well as the window?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the window's `styleMask`?

Comment: @KenThomases I tried .fullSizeContentView but I loose the option maximize the window (the circles buttons in the left corner)

Comment: If the `styleMask` doesn't include `.resizable`, the window won't be resized.

Comment: If add `window?.styleMask = [.resizable]` now I can resize the window but three little buttons in the left side are gone. How can recover this buttons ?

Comment: @KenThomases I switch to `window?.styleMask = [.resizable, .titled, .closable]` now the buttons are showing. but when I click the button to make it full screen still shows as the image I post above

Comment: Have you (perhaps unintentionally) set the window's `contentMaxSize`, perhaps in the Size inspector in IB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your problem is not related to the window setup.

You must use layout constrains or classical springs and struts to layout and automatically resize your view dependent on the window content view size.

You can set all this options comfortable in Interface builder.

Constrains approach:

[image]

Springs and struts:

[image]

Basic window configuration can be done in Interface builder as well.

Best wishes.